# How to make FB Recommend button clickable more than once?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I want to allow users to spam their own walls so I need the facebook recommend/like button to be clickable more than once. I'm using the iframe implemntation.

Is this actually possible?

Comment: I don't know - I'm curious though, why do you want that?

Comment: Facebook's spammy enough as is. Do you really want to let people fill up their walls with "I like candy. I like candy. I like candy. I like candy"? Even if some users want the feature, consider that probably the other 6 bajillion users will only want to torture you (and the spammer) to death for that useless flood.

Answer (score 0):

No. One user can only 'Like' or 'Recommend' once. There is a difference in the way the button shows up if the user has already clicked on 'Like' or 'Recommend'.

FWIW, here is how it looks: [Before Liking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfnTc.jpg), [After Liking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wU2.jpg)